# как передать WebDriver импортированному тесту?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, python-unittest

Необходимо выполнить тесты из основного модуля и импортированные из внешнего в одном окне браузера. Но что-то идет не так:

***main_tests.py:***

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import import_test_set

class MainTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.url = "https://www.google.com/"
        s = Service("../chromedriver/chromedriver")
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_00_01_open_site(self):
        """открытие сайта"""
        print('test_00_01_open_site')

        self.driver.get(self.url)
        self.assertIn("Google", self.driver.title)

    def test_00_02_imported_tests(self):
        """импортированные тесты"""
        print('test_00_02_imported_tests')

        imported_tests = import_test_set.ImportTestSet()
        imported_tests.set_driver(self.driver)
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(import_test_set)

        result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
        self.assertEqual(result.failures, [])
```

***import_test_set.py:***

```
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class ImportTestSet(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.i_wait = 5

    def set_driver(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def test_00_02_01_enter(self):
        """переход на страницу авторизации"""
        print('test_00_02_01_enter')

        self.driver.implicitly_wait(self.i_wait)
        a_enter = self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Войти')
        a_enter.click()
        page_title = self.driver.title
        self.assertEqual(page_title, 'Google Аккаунты')
   
    def runTest(self):
        pass
```

при выполнении получаю ошибку:

> File "C:\Users...\import_test_set.py", line 17, in
> test_00_02_01_enter
> self.driver.implicitly_wait(self.i_wait) AttributeError: 'ImportTestSet' object has no attribute 'driver'

не могу понять почему драйвер не передается в импортируемый тест.
И, кажется, независимо от этого не срабатывает определение элемента (кнопки "Войти") по связанному тексту и любому другому его атрибуту - кнопка не нажимается

что в коде не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо [@frankfalse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18108367/frankfalse) за помощь:

***import_test_set.py:***

```
class ImportTestSet(unittest.TestCase):

    # ----> add the following attribute driver
    driver = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.i_wait = 5

    # ----> remove or stop to use the method set_driver()
    #def set_driver(self, driver):
    #    self.driver = driver
```

***main_tests.py:***

```
def test_00_02_imported_tests(self):
    print('test_00_02_imported_tests')

    # ---> remove the following instructions
    #imported_tests = import_test_set.ImportTestSet()
    #imported_tests.set_driver(self.driver)

    # ---> add the following instruction to set the attribute driver of ImportTestSet
    import_test_set.ImportTestSet.driver = self.driver
```